# Laravel 5.2 - Error while installing laravel using composer with git bash

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am new to laravel, and while installing laravel using composer I am seeing an error. I tried finding the solution, but end up finding nothing. I also tried **composer update**. But still face issue while installing, below is the command.

**COMMAND:**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel cms 5.2
```

**ERROR:**

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 
>       'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' 
>       (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>       PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): 
>       failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>       PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 
>       'C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' 
>       (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>       Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned 
>       with error code 255

I have tried reinstalling composer and still the problem arise. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel cms "5.2.*"
```

*Note* If you already have a `cms` directory, delete it first before you run the above command.*

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#installing-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer dump-autoload` will solve this error.

Comment: I did that, but still there is an error
** [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "database" which does not appear to be a
  file nor a folder**

Comment: Delete `composer.lock` file and run `composer update` again.